How to handle errors when using Eventbridge pipe with SQS and ECS?
When using Eventbridge pipe with SQS queue as a source and ECS task as destination: How is error handling supposed to be handled ?
From what I understood, since Eventbridge will make an asynchronous API call to ECS (To run the task with the message), Eventbridge will then directly delete the message from the SQS queue without waiting.
It means that if the ECS task encounters an error while processing the message, the message will be lost.
Is there any best practices regarding this use case ?
Thank you!
